# Configure URL redirection in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs) is Google Cloud's offering of [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), the workflow management platform.

Composer [deploys the Airflow web server in an AppEngine instance](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/architecture#private-ip), and thus [the URL of the deployed webapp is non-customizable](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface#before_you_begin). As a service deployed in AppEngine, the host name of the URL ends in ".appspot.com", but has an automatically generated prefix, and is not easily predictable.

How can I assign a custom, easier to remember host name to point to this service?

In particular, there are firewall rules in place, so a firewall exception for *.appspot.com would be too wide.

Comment: I would probably suggest a workaround. As I remember, upon deployment, it is possible to get the URL as one of output parameters. Thus, on the next step of the CICD - it should be possible to modify firewall rules to allow access...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get inspiration from [my article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d) and perform a similar thing, not with Cloud Run but with App Engine URL.

I mean:

- Create an internet NEG to appsport.com
- Add the host header equals to your Cloud Composer appspot URL.
- Create your Load Balancer with the domain name that you want.

I didn't test; let me know if it's suitable and if it works for you.